# inserting row numbers in datagridview by only changing its proprty in c# .net,

Tags: c#, ado.net

I want to generate row number automatically in Datagridveiw header by changing its property  in c# .net,Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

For Generating row number DataGridView using  c# you can use **RowPostPaint** event of DataGridView

```
  private void dataGridView1_RowPostPaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPostPaintEventArgs e)
        {
            // get the row number in leading zero format, 
            //  where the width of the number = the width of the maximum number
            int RowNumWidth = dataGridView1.RowCount.ToString().Length;
            StringBuilder RowNumber = new StringBuilder(RowNumWidth);
            RowNumber.Append(e.RowIndex + 1);
            while (RowNumber.Length < RowNumWidth)
                RowNumber.Insert(0, "0");

            // get the size of the row number string
            SizeF Sz = e.Graphics.MeasureString(RowNumber.ToString(), this.Font);

            // adjust the width of the column that contains the row header cells 
            if (dataGridView1.RowHeadersWidth < (int)(Sz.Width + 20))
                dataGridView1.RowHeadersWidth = (int)(Sz.Width + 20);

            // draw the row number
               e.Graphics.DrawString(
                RowNumber.ToString(), 
                this.Font, 
                SystemBrushes.ControlText, 
                e.RowBounds.Location.X + 15, 
                e.RowBounds.Location.Y + ((e.RowBounds.Height - Sz.Height) / 2));
        }
```

Right Click on the DataGridView, go through Properties. Then you will get a window like below. Go through the events in the top of the properties you can see  several events that can be handled by the DataGridView.Select the RowPostPaint and  double click on the right side will create an event on code behind.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering but my coding is in c# not in asp.net ,if you know it than please answer

Comment: or should write this code in another asp form can i do it like this?

Comment: I have taken dataGridView1_CellContentClick this DataGridView ,and i am not getting dataGridView1_RowPostPaint this Data_Grid_View  in tool box,what to do? and when i inserted your code as it is it is not showing row number

Comment: Take the properties of the DataGridView and on the event session you can find the RowPostPaint event. Double clik on it gives the event on the code behind and then add the code...

Comment: can you please elaborate that what you mean by event session here,because when i click on DataGridView it is giving me this        on the code behind in Form1.cs(source file)            private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

        }

Comment: please look at the figure that i added

Comment: Actually i am new to .net so i wasn't knowing that we can select events like this ,so thank you for telling this new thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CurrentRow property of the Data Grid

eg. like to change the back color, as follows:

```
myDataGrid.CurrentRow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
```

hope it vl b useful to you kitty...

Comment: if you want to add new information in your answer, you should edit your first answer. Not post new answer. Read [faq]